# knockout mapping plugin async

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

i am using knockout mapping plugin to map data coming from a breeze query to an array.

The below function refresh the array every 3 sec. after receiving data from a breeze query:

```
function refreshArray(itemsArray, predicate, fields, entityName, entityKey) {
    if (predicate) {
        return ds.getProjection(fields, entityName, predicate).then(function (data) {
            ko.mapping.fromJS(data.results, {
                create: function (options) {
                    options.data["isSelected"] = ko.observable(false);
                    return ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data, {});
                }
                , key: function (data) {
                    // Bisogna capire come gestirlo nel caso di una chiave composta.
                    return ko.utils.unwrapObservable(data[entityKey[0].name]);
                }
            }, itemsArray);
        })
    }
    else itemsArray([]);
};
```

with big dataset it's causing a small task freeìzing during the mapping (about 3 sec. over 4K record).

Do you have a suggestion ? (do i have to make the mapping async ? can i use other plugins like knockout.viewmodel ?)

Comment: You should run a JS profile (for example [in Chrome](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/cpu-profiling), but other browsers can do something similar) and find out where the time goes.

Comment: Depending on what browsers you support, you can also look into web workers https://www.google.com/search?q=web+workers

Comment: Which browser are you observibng this in?  If you are getting 4k records that you just got that have no changes then Breeze is having to iterate through the record set every 3 seconds and check for changes to any property.  Consider only sending back records that have changed...

Comment: why not to return subset of your data instead of the whole records?

Comment: The delay is at mapping time, i know that, the matter is not browser related. i was just wonder if i could "hide" the time spent for the mapping process using promises ...

Comment: @danludwig, thx for the suggestion, it's very interesting. Unfortunaltely using web workers it isn't possible to share object between worker and document, it means i cannot map directly the array in the host file.